# ANSIBLE - how to concatenate a string with a list

Tags: list, ansible, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a string which is referenced as variable with a nested list

I looked into the options of using the set_fact and join but to no avail.

```
#config.yml
- name: concatenate 
  module_name:Test
     state: present
     port: {{ env_dc }}{{item.ports}}
  with_items:
      - "{{ my_list }}"

#group_vars\all.yml
env_dc: uk

my_list:
  - {name: switch1, ports: [p1, p2, p3, p4]}
```

I am expecting the following output:
ukp1
ukp2
ukp3
ukp4

But I am getting;

```
"item": {    
    "ports": [     
       "p1",    
       "p2",    
       "p3",    
       "p4"   
     ]
```

Actual Playbook:

[image]

Error message:
[image]

Comment: What is `module_name:Test`? That isn't even valid YAML syntax as written, nor does it appear to be a normal ansible playbook. Have you used a `debug` task to verify that `env_dc` has the value you think it does at that point in the playbook?

Comment: I'm just not showing which ansible module I'm using. Forget about the precision of the syntax cause my original playbook works.I have verified that env_dc does have a value.

Comment: Your output doesn't actually show the output of the task, either.  Of course `item` look like that, because it's the loop variable. Can you show us (a) the actual playbook you're running, and (b) the actual output produced by the playbook?

Comment: @larsks Actual playbook and error above.

Answer (score 3):

If you write this:

```
     port: {{ env_dc }}{{item.ports}}
```

You are not producing a new list formated by concatenating the value in `env_dc` with each item in `item.ports`; you are simply creating a new string that has the contents of `env_dc` followed by the string representation of `item.ports`.  That is, in your example, that would evaluate to something like:

```
uk['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4']
```

You can solve this using the `map` filter (which can apply a filter to all items in a list) and the `regex_replace` filter, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    env_dc: uk
    my_list:
      - name: switch1
        ports:
          - p1
          - p2
          - p3
          - p4
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "ports: {{ item.ports|map('regex_replace', '^', env_dc)|list }}"
      with_items: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Which given your example data would evaluate to:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'name': u'switch1', u'ports': [u'p1', u'p2', u'p3', u'p4']}) => {
    "msg": "ports: [u'ukp1', u'ukp2', u'ukp3', u'ukp4']"
}
```